# "Под()стать"

Tags: орфография

Попадалось в интернете утверждение, что наречие "под()стать" пишется раздельно: "костюм под стать фигуре". Но разве это правильно? Разве не слитно?

Answer (score 5):

Существительное *стать* значит телосложение, общий склад фигуры, тела. НАречие *под стать* значит подходит по стати и, шире, - вообще подходит. ДЛя чего возвращаюсь к значению? В правилах слитного-раздельного написания наречий  говорится о том, что наречие, образованное от существительного с предлогом пишется раздельно, если существительное в определенном значении сохранило хотя бы некоторые падежные формы.  А слово стать эти формы сохранило! Например, "Любуюсь статью это женщины!"

Answer (score 0):

Орфографический словарь подтверждает: слово **под стать** 'кстати', 'пара', 'приличествовать', 'сообразно' пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

В тех же словарях, на которые ссылаются уважаемые оппоненты, можно найти другое наречие "похлеще", которое даётся в слитной форме, и это невзирая на то, что подчиняться оно должно как будто тем же правилам, что и "подстать". Ведь слово "хлеще" тоже сохраняет падежные формы: хлестать, хлещу и т.д.

Comment: Можно попонятнее?  Что за словари, почему похлеще должно следовать тем же правилам, что и под стать - и что вообще это за правила?

Про падежные формы глагола (!) я пока не спрашиваю.

ЗЫ А логика действительно - и под стать, и похлеще.

Comment: Слово ХЛЕЩЕ (а с ним и ПОХЛЕЩЕ)не имеет падежных форм, поскольку является сравнительной степенью прилагательного хлёсткий или наречия хлёстко.

Comment: Спасибо, до меня, кажется, дошло. Но меня интересуют не столько правила грамматики, сколько вопрос о том, откуда берутся сами правила. Мне, убогому, дело представлялось так: кто-то стал наблюдать, как люди говорят и пишут, а потом догадался, какие здесь действуют правила. Ньютон тоже наблюдал за небом, а потом смекнул: «Ага! Здесь действуют такое-то законы!». В словарях Даля и Ушакова наречие "под стать" пишется слитно. Это похоже на то, как если бы Ньютон сказал: «Нет! Мне больше не нравится старый закон!». И планеты стали вращаться в другую сторону.

Answer (score 0):

> **Ларf**:
> В правилах слитного-раздельного написания наречий говорится о том, что наречие, образованное от существительного с предлогом пишется раздельно, если существительное в определенном значении сохранило хотя бы некоторые падежные формы. А слово стать эти формы сохранило! Например, "Любуюсь статью это женщины!"

Так кто же прав? Даль и Ушаков или Лопатин с Ефремовой?

Даль и Ушаков говорят "подстать", стало быть они подстать друг другу. В отличие от них г-н Лопатин явно под стать г-же Ефремовой... Надо понимать под *её женскую* стать?